# Masking Using Kinetic.js

Tags: canvas, kineticjs

I draw two draggable bezier curve and circle using kinetic js.my problem is that i want to find the mask area.is there any way to find intersection point of bezier and circle.Or suggest me best way of masking canvas.i want to draw image on masked(visible) region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compositing can quickly and easily mask intersections, but KineticJS does not offer compositing as a built-in method.

[image]

In particular, 'source-in' compositing will reveal the intersection of existing shapes and a newly drawn shape. So when you draw your new circle over your existing curves, only the intersection of the circle & curves will remain.

A workaround is to use an in-memory html5 canvas to do the compositing and then use that canvas as a source for a Kinetic.Image.

Here's an outline of how to do it:

1. Create an in-memory canvas:

   ```
   var compositingCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
   var context=compositingCanvas.getContext('2d');
   ```
2. Draw your Bezier curves using `context.moveTo` and `context.bezierCurveTo`
3. Set compositing to source-in: `context.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';`
4. Draw your Circle using `context.arc`
5. Create a Kinetic.Image using compositingCanvas as the source:

   ```
   var myMaskedShape=new Kinetic.Image({
       image:compositingCanvas,
       ....
   });
   ```

**[ Add Demo Code showing compositing in html5 canvas ]**

Here's an example of how to use compositing in html5 Canvas to limit your lens image to the intersection of the eye-beziers and the retina-circle.  You can use this html5 Canvas as an image source for your Kinetic.Image (Yes...An html5 canvas can be the source of your Kinetic.Image!).

Good luck with your project!

```js
var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width=300;
var ch=canvas.height=300;
ctx.lineWidth=2;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){

  drawEye(null,'black');
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';
  drawRetina(null,'black');
  ctx.drawImage(img,173-38,150-38,img.width,img.height);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';   

  drawEye('black',null);

}
img.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/stars.png';


function drawEye(stroke,fill){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(225,150);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo( 189,135, 83,75, 75,150);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo( 83,225,  189,165, 225,150);
  ctx.closePath();
  if(fill){ ctx.fill(); }
  if(stroke){ ctx.stroke(); }
}

function drawRetina(stroke,fill){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(173,150,38,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  if(fill){ ctx.fill(); }
  if(stroke){ ctx.stroke(); }
}


function drawEye1(stroke,fill){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(150,100);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo( 125,90, 55,50, 50,100);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo( 55,150,  125,110, 150,100);
  ctx.closePath();
  if(fill){ ctx.fill(); }
  if(stroke){ ctx.stroke(); }
}
```

```css
var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width=300;
var ch=canvas.height=300;
ctx.lineWidth=2;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){

  drawEye(null,'black');
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';
  drawRetina(null,'black');
  ctx.drawImage(img,173-38,150-38,img.width,img.height);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';   

  drawEye('black',null);

}
img.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/stars.png';


function drawEye(stroke,fill){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(225,150);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo( 189,135, 83,75, 75,150);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo( 83,225,  189,165, 225,150);
  ctx.closePath();
  if(fill){ ctx.fill(); }
  if(stroke){ ctx.stroke(); }
}

function drawRetina(stroke,fill){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(173,150,38,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  if(fill){ ctx.fill(); }
  if(stroke){ ctx.stroke(); }
}


function drawEye1(stroke,fill){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(150,100);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo( 125,90, 55,50, 50,100);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo( 55,150,  125,110, 150,100);
  ctx.closePath();
  if(fill){ ctx.fill(); }
  if(stroke){ ctx.stroke(); }
}
```

```html
<h4>Intersection of eye & retina filled with image using compositing</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: hello marKE..my exact problem is that user first select left eye shape region and after that left retina shape and same for right.i used bezier curve for eye shape and circle for retina.i want to find out the common region between bezier and circle ,for that i can place a lens image on that just like http://www.freshlook.com .i  am new on kinetic i tried composition earlier but i fail to get exact result.

Comment: I added example code showing how to use compositing to limit your lens to the intersection of the eye-beziers and the retina-circle. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks markE to give solution for my problem.i will customize it according to my problem..thanks again